# Python pip gives error: Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-9erwl3ee-build/

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, pip

I am trying to install pygame by

> command: pip3 install --user hg+http://bitbucket.org/pygame/pygame

but everytime it is giving the error msg: Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-9erwl3ee-build/

I have tried upgrading setuptools.
OS : Elementary OS Loki
python3

> **command I give:**
>
> pip install --user hg+http://bitbucket.org/pygame/pygame
>
> **Output I get:**
>
> Collecting hg+http://bitbucket.org/pygame/pygame
>   Cloning hg http://bitbucket.org/pygame/pygame to /tmp/pip-bhdorcms-build
>       Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
>
> ```
> WARNING, No "Setup" File Exists, Running "config.py"
> Using UNIX configuration...
>
> /bin/sh: 1: freetype-config: not found
> /bin/sh: 1: freetype-config: not found
> /bin/sh: 1: freetype-config: not found
>
> Hunting dependencies...
> WARNING: "freetype-config" failed!
> SDL     : found 1.2.15
> FONT    : found
> IMAGE   : found
> MIXER   : found
> PNG     : found
> JPEG    : found
> SCRAP   : found
> PORTMIDI: found
> PORTTIME: found
> FREETYPE: not found
> Missing dependencies
>
> ---------------------------------------- Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-bhdorcms-build/
> ```

Comment: Please post the execution log after running it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can confirm this behavior on Ubuntu 16.10.

Do you need the bleeding-edge version of `pygame`? Otherwise I would advice you to install it like this instead to get the latest stable version:

```
pip install pygame
```